# Is there any scripts/sites to find the z-index of Divs

Tags: css, html

Good Day, I used position:absolute for many div's in my website. I have used nearly 35 - 40 divs with absolute property.

Now i have a issue with z-index say some divs get hides, I realize this is because of z-index problem. I never declared z-index in my css.

I need to track the z-index of each divs. Is there any programs or scripts to find the z-index of the div's in my website?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/60 for that.
Use the topography feature or the display z-index featur under "Information"

Comment: Wow! Amazing add-on. Thanks a lot for sharing the great resource, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

First, it sounds like really bad programming having nearly 40 divs all using position:absolute and z-index. I would strongly recommend that you change the code to something more "user friendly".

But in this case, I would use jQuery to track your DIVs.
create an array where you put the ID for each div in.
Then you can loop through it and compare z-index values.

Or loop through the divs using the $.()each function.

Readmore about jQuery each here: http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each

Comment: Hi Steven,

Its not a bad programming..As the requirement is like that. Also i have used 40 divs with absolute property for the whole website not a single page. Thanks for your suggestion..I will try using jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a usual DOM recursive iteration to get to the id of the particular div you want and then display the z-index.

```
element = getFromDOM(your_div_id);
alert (element.style.zindex);
```

However, I would suggest you install Firebug in Firefox and view / alter the z-index of the div you want dynamically. Get Firebug here - http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: Firebug is your friend when it comes to debugging :)